# How to enable mysqli extension on redhat?

Tags: mysql, php, redhat, php.ini

My php.ini says:

Additional .ini files parsed

```
    /etc/php53/php.d/curl.ini,   
 /etc/php53/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php53/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php53/php.d/mysqli.ini,
 /etc/php53/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php53/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php53/php.d/phar.ini, 
/etc/php53/php.d/zip.ini
```

mysqli.ini is loaded..
But  still i get this,

**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found**

- i tried enabling dynamic loading
  and initialize php scripts with **dl("mysqli.so");**
- i also tried recompiling the php source:

  ```
  ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/lib64/mysql --with-
  mysqli=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
  ```

even this didn't work. Can anybody help me solve my problem?

1. Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga).
2. x86_64 GNU/Linux.
3. No access to RHN.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have an active Red Hat subscription, either purchase one, or convert the system to CentOS.

Comment: how did you install php?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using php5.5.x then:

```
$ sudo yum install php55-mysqlnd
```

or:

```
$ yum install php[your version]-mysqli or mysql
```

If you're greater than 5.3:

```
$ yum install php[your version]-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score 0):

So... php -i and phpinfo() does not shown this module?

Check /etc/php53/php.d/mysqli.ini for extension="mysqli.so"
Find your extension dir like "php -i|grep extension_dir"
Check extension path for this module (for example: ls -lha /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so)
If moudule exist, check all needed libs for this mod (ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so)
If module does not exist, install it. (i assume, you are custom compiling php, so u can find this extension in ext/mysqli of php source. Just make && make install it, or u see some errors during install)
Also, you may find some usefull information about missing or incompatible modules in stdout from php -i.

Comment: yes phpinfo() does not show this module!!! php -i|grep extension_dir shows `extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php53/modules => /usr/lib64/php53/modules
`ls -lha /usr/lib64/php53/modules/mysqli.so shows `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 130K Aug 23 06:58 /usr/lib64/php53/modules/mysqli.so` ldd /usr/lib64/php53/modules/mysqli.so shows [libs](http://pastebin.com/Fkf3MnVC)  [phpinfo](http://pastebin.com/9bXAxd6B)

Comment: @nuthan I am running into the same issue. were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Salton Its been a quiet long time. The issue was resolved, but I dont remember exactly how it did. Sorry for that. Anyway, what issues r u facing now?